# Problem when using py.test with a pytorch project via the python extension of visual studio code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pytest, pytorch

I'm working on a pytorch project using visual studio code and trying to use py.test.

However, when trying to discover (or run) tests using the vs-code extension, I get an error (see log) importing torch. When I run pytest from the terminal, everything works fine.

**Question:** What is VS-code doing differently compared to me running `pytest` myself?
How can I fix this?

Thanks

#### Config and further info

- Win10, custom `conda` env, `python=3.7`, `pytest=3.8`, `pytorch=0.4.1 [cuda92]`, vscode `1.27.2`
- When I remove some tests so that all remaining tests do **not** call any `torch` code, everything works fine (i.e. `pytest` config inside vs-code should be correct)
- Python path pointing to correct env is set in vs-code Workspace Settings
- VS Code seems to be using the correct conda env and pytest version according to Python Test Log (see below)
- Running `pytest` directly from terminal works fine (see below)
- I can successfully call modules using `torch` via `python` or `import torch` inside `ipython`
- **Edit 1**: I'm aware of https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518 and have tried some of the more recent suggestions in that thread. (However, I don't think that's really my problem, because as said above I can `import torch` just fine.)
- **Edit 2**: I'm getting the same error when running any modules that `import torch` *inside vs-code's debugger*

#### Output of Vs-Code Pytest Test Log after failed 'Discover Tests'

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-3.8.0, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: c:\Users\stefan\dev\bnelearn, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________ ERROR collecting bnelearn/tests/test_mechanisms.py ______________
ImportError while importing test module 'c:\Users\stefan\dev\bnelearn\bnelearn\tests\test_mechanisms.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
bnelearn\tests\test_mechanisms.py:3: in <module>
    import torch
..\..\Anaconda3\envs\bnelearn\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py:80: in <module>
    from torch._C import *
E   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.12 seconds ===========================
```

#### Output of running pytorch directly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround: 
The issue does not appear when code is started **from the command line with the desired env activated**.